# elif statement won't run in Python

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

This is my code. The last ELIF statement it keeps saying is wrong when ran from codeacademy labs - BATTLESHIP GAME EXERCISE!

```
from random import randint

    board = []
#
# All code functions here

    for x in range(0, 5):
        board.append(["O"] * 5)

    def print_board(board):
        for row in board:
            print " ".join(row)

    print_board(board)

    def random_row(board):
        return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

    def random_col(board):
        return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

# All game variables for row and col guessing

    ship_row = random_row(board)
    ship_col = random_col(board)
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

# Prints the variable chosen randomly
    print ship_row
    print ship_col

#
    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print "Congratulations! You sank my battleship!"
```

THIS STATEMENT. CODEACADEMY KEEPS SAYING IS WRONG EVEN THOUGH IT RUNS

WHAT'S WRONG WITH IT?

```
    elif guess_row not in range(0, len(board)-1) or guess_col not in        
        range(0, len(board)-1):
         print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean"

# final else statement. Prints missed battleship msg 
# end of code   
    else:
        print "You missed my battleship!" # msg lost game
        board[guess_row][guess_col]="X"   # shows guess var
        print_board(board)    

# end of code. Last else statement.
```

Comment: That's because of the stackOverFlow Editor. The elif validation is all in one line in my terminal

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did you even make it run since python is so picky with spaces.

maybe that's it but codecademy let you run it in their console for some reason, if you call the file with python installed on your pc it doesn't run.

```
from random import randint

board = []

# All code functions here

for x in range(0, 5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

# All game variables for row and col guessing

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

# Prints the variable chosen randomly
print ship_row
print ship_col


if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
    print "Congratulations! You sank my battleship!"

# THIS STATEMENT. CODEACADEMY KEEPS SAYING IS WRONG EVEN THOUGH IT 
# RUNS
# WHAT'S WRONG WITH IT?

elif guess_row != (0, len(board)-1) or guess_col != range(0, len(board)-1):
    print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean"
```